# from file to postgresql table

Tags: postgresql

If i have a schema named 'public' and table tbl in it and also data tablename.csv:

```
1   name1
2   name2
```

How to copy a file data in localhost to postgresql in remote host:

```
pg_query($dbConn, "COPY public.tbl FROM 'tablename.csv' DELIMITER '\t' CSV;");
```

Warning: pg_query() [function.pg-query]: Query failed: ERROR: syntax error at or near "\" LINE 1: \COPY public.tbl FROM 'C:/workspace/public.tbl... ^ in C:\workspace...\file.php on line 110.
or pgAdmin III the same command

```
COPY tablename FROM 'C:\workspace\filename.CSV' DELIMITER ' ' CSV;
```

Shows "ERROR: could not open file "C:\workspace\filename.CSV" for reading: No such file or directory".

Comment: @ManiDeep Nonsense. http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.pg-copy-from.php

Comment: The error message tells you're using `\COPY` which is a command of the psql command-line interpreter only. Use `pg_copy_from` instead as mentioned in the previous comment.

Answer (score 2):

The `COPY` command, if passed a filename, refers to a filename on the *server side*.

If you want to `COPY` from a local file you can use `COPY ... FROM stdin`, but it's a bit of a pain to work with directly using most client drivers.

Instead, use [`pg_copy_from`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.pg-copy-from.php), the PHP PostgreSQL driver function that's designed for this job.

Answer (score 0):

From [the fine manual](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-copy.html) . . .

> It is recommended that the file name used in COPY always be specified
>   as an absolute path. This is enforced by the server in the case of
>   COPY TO, but for COPY FROM you do have the option of reading from a
>   file specified by a relative path. The path will be interpreted
>   relative to the working directory of the server process (normally the
>   cluster's data directory), not the client's working directory.

So use an absolute path, and keep in mind that the path is interpreted from the point of view of the server process. If the server can't see your C: drive as a C: drive (and it can't), then you need a different path.

The easiest way to make this work is to upload filename.csv to your database server, and use an absolute path to it.

Comment: he is using it from localhost to remote host, so before using the copy command he needs to send the file into the path in remote host, and the error is clear that file doesn't exist.